# Discord.js client doesn't do anything after compiling

Tags: node.js, discord.js, executable, pkgbuild

i have a basic Discord.js application in a nodejs project. When i launch my file via `node client.js` everything works completly fine, the bot listens to messages/commands and events at all. But after compiling my app to an executable (with node module pkg) the client doesnt work anymore.

I debugged quiet a lot and the mysterious thing is that the `ready` event does fire on the client, but nothing else. In my ready event i've got a `client.user.setActivity('listening')` but that gives an error that it cannot read property of `.setActivity` (Debug of `client.user` was equal to `null`).

You may ask why i want an executable to start my discord bot, well its my project :)

Comment: Do you catch the "ready" event in your main-file or do you use an eventhandler with a structuring of the events?

Comment: I catch the "ready" event in the main process. I think Discord.js doesnt work in an executable, can you try it on your own? Just a simple discordjs app and compile it with pkg to an executable

Comment: I would but I’m not at home rn. You can have a look at [my discord bot](https://github.com/Toasty65/Discord-Bot/tree/develop)